# Are dynamically created classes destroyed just like other objects are?

Tags: python, garbage-collection

To preface this, this is a hypothetical, and just a question that popped into my head while I was prototyping some code. Dynamically creating classes has a pretty narrow range of applicable usages.

In Python, I can dynamically define a class by, for example, nesting its definition inside a def[1]:

```
def NewClass(doc):
  class MyClass(object):
    __doc__ = doc
  return MyClass
```

What happens when the instance of the class becomes unused? Does its refcount go to zero and is it destroyed just like other objects? Or is it handled a little bit specially because its a class? Reading the language docs, I didn't see much anything about class object destruction.

More specifically, if I had code creating these in response to user requests, e.g., so there were thousands or millions being created through the lifetime of a process, would I need to worry about running out of memory because of all the created classes?

[1] e.g., the `type` "function", and probably various meta-class things or `__new__` tricks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, classes are objects too, and are governed by the same reference counting rules.

If all you do with the return value is create instances, then the only reference to the class is the `__class__` attribute on those instances. If there are no more instances of that specific class, it will no longer be referenced and deleted.